# How to makes this checkbox works inside the GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a new ASP.NET developer and trying to use a GridView control as a way for managing the employees in each division. This GridView will show all the employees in the employee table in the database. Now, I am facing the following problem:

FYI, I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name, JobTitle, BadgeNo, IsActive, DivisionCode
Divisions Table: SapCode, DivisionShortcut
```

***(IsActive is like a flag (bit datatype) to indicate if the employee is in an assignment or not)***

**IsActive** will be displayed in the GridView as a Checkbox. If it is checked, it means true and the employee is existed in his division. if it is not checked, it means the employee is not with the division, and it should be hidden from the GridView. **So how to do that? Also, I want to hide (True) text that appears besides the checkbox in the Edit mode. How to do that, too?**

ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active?">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("IsActive")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="isActive" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IsActive")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

**UPDATE:**

I want the employee with all of his information to hidden from the GridView since he is inactive.

Comment: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=5187857

Comment: You need to bind the Checked property, not Text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="isActive" runat="server" Visible='<%# Bind("IsActive")%>' Text='<%# Bind("IsActive")%>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead.
Have removed the text property, so that IsActive would not be visible. Visiblity is controled by IsActive Flag

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active?">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("IsActive")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="isActive" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("IsActive").ToString().Equals("True")  %> />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

**EDIT**

If you want entire row to be hidden for inactive user, you could best to do is filter the inactive user from dataset, before you do a databind() operation. You could even filter it at database end also, but since I do not know the entire scenario, I am suggesting you this.

```
 DataSet filter = ds.Tables[0].Select("IsActive == 'True'");
    gridUser.DataSource = filter;
    gridUser.DataBind();
```

Comment: I ask myself how he want to make the user active when he's inactive since the CheckBox will be invisible. But anyway, that's what he wanted(apart from the `Checked` state).

Comment: I am confused. Do you want to hide the inactive user, or do you want them to still be seen but check box unchecked. If its so you could use Checked Property instead of visible

Comment: Ah, you want entire row to be hidden ?

Comment: I want to hide the inactive user only.

Comment: I want the employee with all of his information to hidden from the GridView since he is inactive

Comment: @Anand: if he wants to hide the complete row, he should omit the record from dbms (`SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE IsActive=1`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, or probably filter it at UI, because he could be using the same record set at other places...